# Mysql dropdown selection to variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, post

I'm fetching data to POST form dropdown selection from mysql with two columns, for example it's Size as XS with a value of 1.05, I'm wondering when the form is submitted Can I Get just the Value of the Size as variable? //I Want to just get the $itl value from FORM selection $rows['timeslogic']. I'm very new to php, couldn't find a way to do it or understand myself.

```
//Izmērs means Size
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<select name="Izmērs" id="izmērs">
<?php 
while($rows = $resultSize->fetch_assoc()){
    $izmers = $rows['Size'];
    $itl = $rows['timeslogic'];
    echo "<option value='$izmers $itl'>$izmers $itl</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //I Want to get just the $itl value from FORM selection $rows['timeslogic']
        $priceitl = $_POST['Size'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I played a bit more of It and found right what I needed, I just had to remove the $izmers variable and leave just the $itl in <option value=>to return just the $itl on post. Well my bad.